# Systeme and Tikzmark

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark, systeme

The following program outputs  the image below. My question: Can I improve this program to achieve a more precise image? The node were not calculated but were achieved by a trial-and-error. Any idea how I can let the program do the calculating instead?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\hspace{2cm}\systeme{x+y=2 @\textcolor{red}{(1)}, 
\tikzmarknode{A}{}x-y\tikzmarknode{C} 
    {}=8\phantom{0}\tikzmarknode{B}{} @\textcolor{red}{(2)}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
%%%First Line
\node at ([yshift=-3ex]A.south) {$2x$};
\node at ([xshift=1.75ex,yshift=-3ex]C.south) {$=$};
\node at ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=-3ex]B.south) {$10$};
%%%Second Line
\node at ([xshift=-.75ex,yshift=-6.5ex]C.south) {$x$};
\node at ([xshift=1.75ex,yshift=-6.5ex]C.south) {$=$};
\node at ([xshift=-1.25ex,yshift=-6.5ex]B.south) {$5$};
%%%Draws line    
\draw[-,black,semithick] ([yshift=-6pt]A.south) to 
      ([yshift=-6pt]B.south);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to go that path, then you may want to use `systeme` to do *all* of the alignment, and Ti*k*Z to do the brace and the horizontal line. (To my greatest surprise `systeme` does not get confused by the `\tikzmarknode`s.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\sysdelim..\hspace{2cm}\systeme{\tikzmarknode{x1}{x}+y=2 @\textcolor{red}{(1)}, 
\tikzmarknode{x2}{x}-y=8@\textcolor{red}{(2)},
\tikzmarknode{2x}{2x}=\tikzmarknode{10}{10},x=5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[decoration={calligraphic brace,raise=0.2em}, decorate, line
 width=0.1em] ([yshift=-0.2em]x2.south west) -- ([yshift=0.3em]x1.north west);
 \path (x2) -- (2x) coordinate[pos=0.65](aux);
 \draw[very thick] (2x.west|-aux) -- (10.east|-aux);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cat yes I like some ideas here. Can you think of a way to move the x over to the right on the second line next to the equal sign? Systeme is aligning it the x-column

Comment: @MathScholar Not really. `systeme` is made for a certain type of layout. If you want something different, you can just work with and ordinary align and some `\llap`, `\rlap`, and maybe the `eqparbox` package.